# Why can we use にせよ in this situation?

Tags: grammar

If I'm not mistaken, にせよ is more or less にしろ and they can be used like にしても.

The thing I don't understand is that normally in Xにする, X is a noun but in this sentence にせよ is used right after a verb in dictionary form(without よう or anything like that) :

> 何をやるにせよ、ベストを尽くしなさい。 No matter what you do, do your best.

Comment: http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%82%8D%E3%81%AB%E3%81%9B%E3%82%88-ni-shironi-seyo/

Comment: Thanks. (I searched before asking this question but I didn't find this page, sorry.)